# moving a 2d object from point a to b without changing its rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to move a 2d object from point a to b without changing its rotation in unity

I've tried to use `Vector2.Lerp()` but its not working

```
Vector2 pointB = new Vector2(20, 10);
Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, pointB, 3F);
```

The code should move the object from point a to b in 3F seconds

Answer (score 1):

First, `Vector2.Lerp` doesn't change the value of the first parameter. You'll want to assign the new value to `transform.position` if you want to change the transform's position that way.

Secondly, you need to update the transform's position once every frame to keep the transform moving smoothly.

Thirdly, `Vector2.Lerp` will only produce positions between start and end with a `t` between 0 and 1. This `t` should relate to the ratio of how much time has passed since this movement started over how much time will complete the movement.

This is a good use for a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html):

```
private IEnumerator GoToInSeconds(Vector2 pointB, float movementDuration)
{
    Vector2 pointA = transform.position;
    float timeElapsed = 0f;
    while (timeElapsed < movementDuration)
    {
        yield return null;
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(pointA, pointB, timeElapsed/movementDuration);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to use it in `Start`:

```
void Start() 
{
    Vector2 pointB = new Vector2(20, 10);
    StartCoroutine(GoToInSeconds(pointB, 3f));
}
```

Comment: Little tip: For additional ease-in and ease-out you could use `Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, timeElapsed/movementDuration)`